# Java method overriding and inheritance

Tags: java, oop, inheritance, overriding

```
class Dad {
    private static final String me = "dad";
    protected  String getMe() {
        return me;
    }
    protected  void printMe() {
        System.out.println(getMe());
    }
}

class Son extends Dad {
    private static final String me = "son";
    protected  void printMe() {
       System.out.println(getMe());
    }
}

class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Son son = new Son();
        son.printMe();
    }
}
```

In this case, the reference "son" of the "Son" type and since the method printMe() is non-static, the code of the method from the class Son will be executed.
But since the Son class has not redefined the method getMe(), the method code from the ancestor class will be executed.
So we get "dad".

Second case:

```
class Dad {
    private static final String me = "dad";
    protected  String getMe() {
        return me;
    }
    protected  void printMe() {
        System.out.println(getMe());
    }
}

class Son extends Dad {
    private static final String me = "son";
    protected  String getMe() {
        return me;
   }


class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Son son = new Son();
        son.printMe();
    }
}
```

Reasoning in a similar way in that case the Son class has not redefined the method printMe(), so the code of the method printMe() from the class Dad should be executed.
But we get "Son".Why?

And then what about inheritance? That is, if the heir does not override the ancestor's method, then they together share the code of the ancestor's method?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the first case `son.printMe()` calls `Son`'s `printMe()` (since `Son` overrides that method), which calls `Dad`'s `getMe()` (since `Son` didn't override that method), which returns "dad".

In the second case `son.printMe()` calls `Dad`'s `printMe()` (since `Son` didn't override that method), which calls `Son`'s `getMe()`, since `Son` overrides that method. Therefore "son" is printed.

Comment: @harp1814 that's correct (unless the ancestor's method is inaccessible to the child class (for example, if it's private), in which case it cannot be directly called by code of the child class).

Comment: But the methods are protected , that means child can see such ancestor's method.

Answer (score 1):

In the second scenario, you're calling `Dad#printMe`, which, in turn, calls `getMe`. Since `Son` does override it, `Son#getMe` is called. That method returns "Son", which is then printed by `printMe`.

Answer (score 0):

You are overriding same same method with tge diff class but the parameters are same for that tge main method is calling the son method

Answer (score 0):

Case 2:
  `son.printMe()` will call `Dad` class `printMe()` as is not not everriden in `Son` class. Now it will look for `getMe()` in the nearest implementation class in the herarchy, i.e. `Son` class. Now `Son#getMe()` will look for the variable `me` in this implementation class, and finds with value `"son"`, so is getting printed. Keep in mind that `private static final String me = "dad";` and `private static final String me = "son";` are two different private variables belong to two different classes. Had there been no definition of `me` variable in the `Son` class, you would have got a compilation error.